# How to Unsubscribe MessagingCenter if user press hardware back button in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

On my button click event I subscribe my messaging center

```
    bool isDataReceived = false;
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Dimention>(this, "Print", (sender) =>
                                    {
                                        isDataReceived = true;
                                        PopulateData(sender);
                                        if (isDataReceived)
                                        {
                                            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Dimention>(this, "Print");
                                        }
                                    });
```

I am sending the data from a Popup Window

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Dimention>(data, "Print");
```

But how to unsubscribe the messaging center when user press hardware back button without sending values.

Comment: i think you could  unsubscribe in the OnDisappearing() method .

Comment: Can you tell me if I Unsubscribe the MessagingCenter multiple times,then what happen?

Comment: nothing happened,but we usually Subscribe on OnAppearing and unsubscribe on OnDisappearing !

Comment: Safely Unsubscribe it before subscribing every time.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the BackButton event

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {    

              base.OnBackButtonPressed();

              MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Dimention>(this, "Print");    
              return false;    

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also make sure that you are unsubscribing from the messaging center by adding the code to the OnDisappearing method:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Dimention>(this, "Print");
}
```